# How can I draw social network of twitter users using NetworkX and pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, pymongo, networkx

I have consumed a bunch of tweets from Twitter, storing them in my localdrive mongodb via pymongo. I would now like to draw a graph of the relations between the different users found in my collection - essentially graphing a social network - using NetworkX. As a complete noob, I have no idea how to do this - any thoughts? Code snippets or links to code welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like an interesting project, but your question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow as it's written. Why not start with the documentation/examples of NetworkX? http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an introduction to the subject, watch [Gilad Lotan's lecture](http://vimeo.com/53061411) and see [his slides](http://www.slideshare.net/giladlotan/pydata-gilad-networkxupload) and if you have difficulty afterwards, maybe come back with specific code-based questions?

Comment: Thanks for that. Still new to stackoverflow so learning as I go along.